# How to relocate to settings from app?

Tags: android, eclipse, gps

I'm making an application in Eclipse wherein you need to activate your GPS. Since we can't activate the GPS through an app, how can we relocate the user to the "settings>location access"?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the following `Intent` after you detect the user has GPS turned off:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```